# c memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have the following problem. The code is this

```
num_tokens++;
words = (char**) realloc(words, sizeof(char**) * (num_tokens + 1) );
words[num_tokens] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(tmp)+1 );
strcpy(words[num_tokens], tmp);
```

where num_tokens is initially set to 0 and words contains, initially, one pointer to a string. I find that when num_tokens gets to one, and tmp is copied into words[1], words[0] changes as well. What might be the problem?

thanks

Comment: I know one problem already: Assuming `words` is a `char **`, you should call `realloc` with `sizeof(char *)` instead of `sizeof(char **)`. Also, is this C or C++? Your title says one but tags say the other. (And yes, they are different.)

Comment: @chris lutz, what difference would that make because in both cases sizeof operator will return the size of a pointer. I agree it is not clear, but functionally would there be a difference?

Comment: @Chris Taylor - The C standard makes no guarantee that all pointer types are the same size. It _should_ work on any sane system, but why write wrong code?

Comment: Code looks OK to me. I think the problem lies elsewhere. Or post a simple complete test case?

Comment: Second (again unrelated) problem: `x = realloc(x, n)` can leak memory if the resize fails. Use `tmp = realloc(x, n); if(tmp) x = tmp; else /* failed to resize, but we still have x */;`

Comment: Code looks looks OK to me, but instead of the malloc+strcpy to copy the string you may want to use strdup, it does the same thing and it's more clear.

Comment: @Giuseppe - `strdup` is not standard. In the unlikely event that the OP doesn't have it, however, it can be easily implemented in terms of `malloc` and `strcpy` (or `memcpy`), so it's still a good idea to use it.

Comment: Indeed, it's better to use `memcpy` when reimplementing `strdup` because you've already had to find the length of the string in order to allocate memory for it…

Comment: Honestly sounds like memory over/underflow elsewhere on the heap, overwriting the old data?

Comment: Oh please, please, please, don't cast the pointer returned by `malloc` to `char *`. It will lead to disaster if you forget to include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: How is words initialized to begin with? Do you allocate a char* array with one element and put a string pointer in it?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but replacing the last 2 lines with `strdup` would give much more readable code. Also, never cast the results of allocation functions, and never write `sizeof(char)` because it suggests to people reading the code that you didn't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

There seems a discrepancy between your counter and the meaning you assign to it. The num_tokens reflects the number of tokens you have in your words array. That means that in your allocation you should allocate 'num_tokens' and not 'num_tokens+1'.

Then, you should assign at num_tokens-1.

If you do not, you will as far as I see it never write into the 0 position, which might lead to unitialized data there, and your consequent feeling that the data 'changed' or got 'overwritten'

Summarized: words[0] will never be written to with this type of code and you will find random data there.

Comment: Questioner says `words contains, initially, one pointer to a string`. So either `words` is a `char *` and everything is lost, or `words` is a properly allocated `char **` whose first and only entry *already* contains a `char *` that points to the string. If so, it's probably *that* string that gets overwritten.

Comment: Makes no sense: If words contains already 1 string, semantically speaking num_tokens should be 1, not 0.

Comment: ( possibly due to a misunderstanding of when postfix ++ happens )

Comment: `num_tokens` becomes `1` in the questioner's very first line of code, and he `realloc()` s `num_tokens + 1` pointers, so that's a semantically confusing but still working scenario. Of course, if `words[0]` is left uninitialized, anything goes.

Comment: I'm not sure. He _says_ that words[0] is initialized, but we do not _see_ it. Where is the allocation of the intial words array to the proper size and where is the assignment to words[0] ?

Answer (score 0):

```
num_tokens++; // 0 => 1

strcpy(words[num_tokens], tmp); // copy tmp to words[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `num_tokens++;` after `strcpy();` because at the strcpy line, num_tokens is already 1. num_tokens 0 is not defined. Thanks.